# Heroku fails to install dependency - How do I fix it?

Tags: python, heroku

I'm trying to push an app to Heroku (first time) and it continues to fail when attempting to install on of the dependencies in the requirements.txt file.

The dependency is for the [etsy-python](https://github.com/mcfunley/etsy-python) library ("pip install etsy" fails).

Locally, I was able to get this to work by downloading and building the source. How can I get past this issue with Heroku?

requirements.txt:

```
Flask==0.9
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
etsy==0.3.1
geopy==0.94.2
httplib2==0.7.7
oauth2==1.5.211
python-etsy==0.1.2
python-twitter==0.8.4
requests==1.0.4
requests-oauth==0.4.1
simplejson==3.0.4
```

Comment: Post your requirements.txt?

Answer (score 1):

I was able to fix this by modifying the requirements.txt as follows:

Although the pypi package for Etsy is not working, the source is ok and builds without problems.

```
Flask==0.9
Jinja2==2.6
Werkzeug==0.8.3
-e git+https://github.com/mcfunley/etsy-python.git#egg=etsy-python
geopy==0.94.2
httplib2==0.7.7
oauth2==1.5.211
python-etsy==0.1.2
-e git+https://github.com/bear/python-twitter.git#egg=python-twitter
requests==1.0.4
requests-oauth==0.4.1
simplejson==3.0.4
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting this error when I try to install etsy locally:

```
ValueError: Invalid IPv6 URL
```

I'd say that the official py-etsy is outdated and broken, the Github repo was last updated a year ago: https://github.com/mcfunley/etsy-python. This library is more recent (5 months ago): https://github.com/priestc/python-etsy.

It's not on pypi, but clone it locally and include it in your project.